# How to parse images posted by user in google reviews?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am working on a scraping project to scrape google maps reviews, but I got struck when I have to parse images posted by users. I tried this method which only gives me the first image posted by user :

```
    $('.gws-localreviews__google-review').each((i,el) => {
    images[i] = $(el)
    .find(".EDblX .JrO5Xe").attr("style")
    })
```

I am scraping google reviews by this URL: `https://www.google.com/async/reviewDialog?hl=en&async=feature_id:0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0,next_page_token:,sort_by:,start_index:,associated_topic:,_fmt:pc`

Here is my response:

```
[
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPgClEw3JwTLJOuf-DqC2xtZRodoavkpYVFBYqu=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOs9TSNoyYmW1GL4SH9PlkAihvWsUbMTn-8O2Sj=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMBRGdJb3zL1rME20osajG-bosdIV8U82VTYS1n=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOBuGDXFDhJP69LNo6yI9cZWcjSVHpVfPBNoKyL=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipP7wBZt8Kilm8VF75T8amjMrZ7ZkOpmtb0nHChF=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOixJabuSd4mSHnveU5JSQ1ZszHJ6Hn-pkeosiY=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPyOXO1vnyTXVnlkPJNLlnoHYHEna36vYnrqwE=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPReBboes7S7lNklRT21pwn096JUQVJbTX3VRRA=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNPLvARJu1vDk03r_y4fp8f7aDDvzRX-7yJklW8=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)',
  'background-image:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMW3jp20hjKwuvhogH9ZC8IeH8QhQTUESH_ycNX=w100-h100-p-n-k-no)'
 ]
```

But what I want an object containing one user images, then a second a object containing a second user images and so on.

I want the results like this:

```
[
{
 "All image's links posted by user 1"
},
{
 "All images links posted by user 2"
}
{
 "All images links posted by user 3"
},
{
 "All images links posted by user 4"
},
{
........
}
]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what your ideal result should look like.

Comment: Check now, I updated the question.

Comment: It's really not clear how the response you have becomes the result you want. How do I know which image in the response is from user 1, 2, 3, etc?!

Comment: I think you have not read the question properly, I am saying currently I am receiving only 1st index images for all users who have posted images, see this : https://www.google.com/maps/place/Eiffel+Tower/@48.8583701,2.2944813,15z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x0:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813!9m1!1b1 

In this link you can clearly see, 1st user has posted fifteen images, 2nd user four images,
that's what I want, I want objects containing links of images in the format I have described in the question. If the user hasn't posted images than that object should be parsed blank.

Comment: https://serpapi.com/google-maps-reviews-api -----> see this sample response for more understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer, it was a bit tricky but yeah it will be solved like this :

```
 $(".gws-localreviews__google-review").each((i, el) => {
     images[i] = $(el)
    .find(".EDblX .JrO5Xe")
    .toArray()
    .map($)
    .map(d => d.attr("style").substring(21 , d.attr("style").lastIndexOf(")")))
     });
 })
```

It will return the response like this:

```
[
 [
  All images posted by user 1,
 ],
 [
   All images posted by user 2,
 ],
 [.........
]
```